# In GDB, what does *(x+value) = value do?

Tags: c, pointers, gdb, memory-address, dereference

I understand that

`*` = dereference

`*x` = dereferencing `x` to grab the value in `x` if `x` is a pointer.

`*x = 5` , set `x` = 5 if `x` is a pointer and a variable `x` exists.

What  does the +value portion do here?

```
Ie. 

x = 5 

*ptr;

ptr = &x

*ptr gives us 5.
```

Comment: Firstly, there's no `*x` in the snippet you posted. Secondly, `*x = 5` does not set `x` to `5`, it sets `*x` to `5`.

Comment: That's normal C syntax. About the details, you should consult your C book.

Answer (score 2):

`x + 5` adds `5*sizeof(*x)` to the value of `x` and dereferences that location.

`*(x + 5)` is exactly equivalent to `x[5]`.

Comment: so if it was x+1 then 1*sizeof(*x) would result in just the base address for x. 

Thank you!

Comment: @TigerCode Actually `0*sizeof(*x)`, when added to `x`, gives you the base address.